# How to load view if UIViewController is having more than one UIView

Tags: ios4

In my app i have one UIViewController and there are many UIView which i want to load on particular action (for instance BTN Tap) so how can i achieve this programatically .
if any one has solution please let me know.

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can bind all the views using IBOutlet like suppose you have view1 and view2 and one default view. Now you want to display view1 on btnTap then you can do like this [self.view addSubview:view1]; make sure to bind the view using IBOutlet

Comment: can i add animation to its load

Comment: yes you can use this code snippet [UIView beginAnimation:nil context:nil]; [UIView setAnimationDuration:durationYouWant]; //your animation related code like changing frames,reducing alpha etc. [UIView commitAnimation]; I have used the above 3 lines of code many places

Comment: thnx can do the same thing for other components like uibutton textfield

Comment: all those components who inherited UIView

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `addSubview` method of `UIView`, like this:

```
[controller.view addSubview:subview];
```

where `controller` is your `UIViewController` (of course, if you are putting that code inside of it, your controller is `self`).